# How to send selected value from jsp page to action class?

Tags: java, html, struts-1

I have this code in jsp page:

```
<select id="DateReport" style="width: 150px;">
        <option value="1"> 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>
```

How do I send the selected value to action class in Struts 1.2?

Comment: is the name attribute not working,like input field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a property in your form `MyForm` declared in your `struts-config.xml` file:

```
<form-bean name="myForm" type="foo.MyForm" />
[...]
```

and associate it with your action

```
<action path="/myAction" name="myForm" type="foo.MyAction" scope="request">
```

In your form:

```
public class MyForm extends ActionForm { 
    private String myValue; 
    [....] 

    // Getters and setters for all attributes 
}
```

Then in your JSP:

```
<html:form action="/myAction.do" method="post" >
    [...]

    <html:select styleId="DateReport" property='myValue' style="width: 150px;">
        <html:option value="1"> 1 </html:option>
        <html:option value="2"> 2 </html:option>
        <html:option value="3"> 3 </html:option>
    </html:select>

    [...]
</html:form>
```

In your action's `execute()`, you could get the value:

```
MyForm myForm = (MyForm) form; 
String value = myForm.getMyValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

your 'select' is missing a NAME. if it has a name, it will go to the server as an http parameter (and the server doesn't mind whether this came from a 'select' or text input...).

```
<form action="YOUR_ACTION" method='post'>
    <select name="dateReport" id="DateReport" style="width: 150px;">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    </select>       

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

You can even change the form method to 'post' and press submit, just to see the parameter with your own eyes, e.g.  http://YOUR_ACTION?dateREport=1

From this point, you can consume the parameter just like any other. Forget it came from a 'select'. If you're really using the old struts 1.x then you need FormBean as described here: http://userpages.umbc.edu/~tarr/jst/lectures/S03-Struts-Beans.pdf

In short, you'll need a bean that describes the form parameters, e.g

```
class MyForm extends ActionForm{
  private int dataReport;
  // .. constructor, getDataReport(), setDataReport() ...
}
```

Then register it in the struts 1 xml:

```
<struts-config>
 <form-beans>
   <form-bean name="myForm" type="mypackage.MyForm"/>
 </form-beans>
 <action-mappings>
 ...
 <action path=".." type="mypackage.MyAction" name="myForm" scope="request">
...
```

Comment: Just two small side notes: (1) did you really mean struts 1, it's quite old